# Which country is the Bitcoin core wallet in?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, taxes

can you tell me which country the Bitcoin core wallet belongs to. I want to return the tax paid, and for this I need to withdraw all funds from the United States.

Comment: Bitcoin Core is an open-source project. It doesn't belong to any country. The project does not control any user funds, and there is nothing to return.

Comment: I have already paid tax and I need to withdraw all funds from the US territory. Only then will the tax paid be returned to me.

Comment: This is a question for your tax advisor. It is entirely unrelated to Bitcoin Core; that's not even a legal entity.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core is open-source software run by you. Since you control the funds, I would expect that they reside in the same country as you. I am neither a lawyer nor a tax consultant, but you should probably talk to one of those if you being in control of your funds is insufficient to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some jurisdictions are starting to consider the funds to be "physically located" (a legal fiction, obviously :D) where the private keys are physically located, I assume the corresponding persistent storage.

This should be straightforward enough for many users, but I don't know how is that going to work for communities where any member can use any of the private keys, and at least one private key is known to more than one person, each person under a different jurisdiction.

Back to your case, I'm lost missing a lot of detail. As others have written, you might prefer to ask a professional. If you want a cheap approximation, you might find basic tax answers at [Money SE](https://money.stackexchange.com) and advanced tax law answers at [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com).